# Logitech Pro Keyboard Driver for Ubuntu or Debian?

Tags: logitech

I have a Logitech Pro gaming keyboard and need a driver to make the RGB lighting work properly.

Comment: Doesn't Logitech lock these lighting features behind proprietary software that only works on Windows, maybe Mac?  What is the exact model keyboard that you have?

Answer (score 2):

There is no such driver.

The software for those leds are proprietary and only available on the list of supported systems noted with your keyboard.

Even on notebooks having such features on unsupported operating systems it is only capable of using 1 color and you can turn it on/off and change it brightness. Nothing else.

Comment: Same with hyperx same with steelcase.

Answer (score 1):

On my Linux Mint Debian Edition I can do everything I want with my new Logitec Pro keyboard and the package 'g810-led'.

```
sudo apt install g810-led
```

This supplies a command, `g810-led`. If you invoke it without arguments, it will explain how to use it. For example:

```
g810-led --list-keyboards
```

This command will tell you what keyboards you have connected.

```
g810-led -a AA0000
```

This sets all the LEDs to solid red. (RGB color code. No blinking.)

```
g810-led --help-samples
```

This will suggest several commands you can try to tweak the settings in different ways.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you both for your answers. I have found a work-around.  My computer is set up for dual boot.  I boot it up in Windows first, adjust the keyboard lighting, restart and boot Linux.  Once the keyboard is powered up, it remembers its settings.

Comment: Whilst this isn’t an Ubuntu solution, I think it’s a shame it’s been down-voted - you’ve found a practical solution to your problem, well done.